# RabbitMQ authentication using Azure ADB2C tokens is not working

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, cryptography, rabbitmq, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to use Azure AD as OAuth server for RabbitMQ authentication. For this i want to use Azure ADB2C tokens.
I have enabled RabbitMq's oauth2 plugin. And i want to use signing key as public private key setup.

Few details regarding setup i have before reaching to this question...

```
1. I have Azure ADB2C setup to authenticate my users to our REST API in application. This works fine.
2. I tried to authenticate RabbitMQ with open source OAuth 2 server like UAA, this works fine too.
```

Idea is to use JWT token that Azure ADB2C generates to authenticate & authorize users to the RabbitMQ. server.
I have private key from Azure ADB2C User Flow generated Metadata document JWKS URI. So i used this JWKS URI - JWT token to generate public key.
I have provided the above generated public key to RabbitMQ config as follows

```
{rabbitmq_auth_backend_oauth2, [
{resource_server_id, <<"rabbitmq">>},
{key_config, [
  {default_key, <<"key-1">>},
  {signing_keys,
    #{<<"key-1">> => {pem, <<"-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAtVKUtcx/n9rt5afY/2WF
NvU6PlFMggCatsZ3l4RjKxH0jgdLq6CScb0P3ZGXYbPzXvmmLiWZizpb+h0qup5j
znOvOr+Dhw9908584BSgC83YacjWNqEK3urxhyE2jWjwRm2N95WGgb5mzE5XmZIv
kvyXnn7X8dvgFPF5QwIngGsDG8LyHuJWlaDhr/EPLMW4wHvH0zZCuRMARIJmmqiM
y3VD4ftq4nS5s8vJL0pVSrkuNojtokp84AtkADCDU/BUhrc2sIgfnvZ03koCQRoZ
mWiHu86SuJZYkDFstVTVSR0hiXudFlfQ2rOhPlpObmku68lXw+7V+P7jwrQRFfQV
XwIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----">>}
         }
      }]}]}
```

I have created an AD user in Azure ADB2C and assigned it to RabbitMQ app registered over Azure. I have provided default scopes to the RabbitMQ app registered with rabbitMQ-permissions like rabbitmq.read... etc. and I have provided default API permission to App registered.
Now in my java application i am trying to make connection to RabbitMQ with following code

```
CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider =
new OAuth2ClientCredentialsGrantCredentialsProviderBuilder()
    .tokenEndpointUri("http://****/B2C_1_RabbitMQ/oauth2/v2.0/token")
    .clientId("rabbit_client_from_Azure").clientSecret("rabbit_secret_from_Azure")
    .grantType("password")
    .parameter("username", "rabbit_admin_from_Azure")
    .parameter("password", "rabbit_admin_from_Azure")
    .build();

connectionFactory.setCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection(); // Line 1
```

When i run above code, **Line 1** it gives me error as  below

```
Exception in thread "main" com.rabbitmq.client.impl.OAuthTokenManagementException: HTTP request for token retrieval did not return 200 response code: 400
```

I am not sure why i am getting above error. I initially thought it would be a matter of scopes/permission from Azure ADB2C registered RabbitMQ app, but i am not able to figure out what i am missing here.
Any help here is much appreciated.

Comment: Is B2C_1_RabbitMQ an ROPC policy? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-ropc-policy?tabs=app-reg-ga&pivots=b2c-user-flow

Comment: @JasSuri-MSFT yes it is ROPC policy, i was able to get the token from Azure ADB2C by creating app over azure with implict grants....now challenge is coming with , when i send the token to rabbitMQ for authentication then its "error": "not_authorised", i am checking public key with rabbitMQ and private provided by Azure are matching or not

Answer (score 0):

I have gotten this working by using jwks_url in key_config instead of adding the keys themselves to the config like this:

```
    {key_config, [
      {jwks_url, <<"https://login.microsoftonline.com/your tenant id/discovery/v2.0/keys">>}
    ]}
```

Just replace "your tenant id" with the id for your tenant.